# ModelState.IsValid returns false when it should be true

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a pretty simple MVC 2 form.  It has two dropdowns, user and role.  The employee dropdown passes validation, and the role dropdown does not, regardless of what I select. There is no default "empty" option although I plan to implement one, which is why I need the validation to work. It fails both client and server validation.  I just can't see why one would work and one does not!

The Form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, new { AllEmployees = Model.AllEmployees, RoleList = Model.RoleList })%>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add New User" />
    </p>

    <% } %>

<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

The Editor Template:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId) %>
            <%: Html.RequiredMarkFor(model => model.UserId) %>
        </div>   
    </td>    
    <td>    
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, new SelectList(ViewData["AllEmployees"] as IEnumerable, "UserId", "DisplayName", Model.UserId)) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId>
    </div>    
    </td>       
</tr>     

<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccessLevel)%>
            <%: Html.RequiredMarkFor(model => model.AccessLevel)%>
        </div>   
    </td>    
    <td>    
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccessLevel, new SelectList(ViewData["RoleList"] as IEnumerable, Model.AccessLevel))%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccessLevel)%>
        </div>    
    </td>       
</tr>
```

The Metadata:

```
    [DisplayName("Employee")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an employee.")]
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "User Id must be less than 8 characters.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false,
                            HtmlEncode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public object UserId { get; set; }


    // Validation rules for Access Level
    [DisplayName("Role")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the role for this user.")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Role must be under 15 characters.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false,
                            HtmlEncode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public object AccessLevel { get; set; }
```

The Get Action:

```
    List<String> roles = (from o in txDB.Users
                                      select o.AccessLevel).Distinct().ToList(); 

    var viewModel = new UserViewModel
    {
        User = new User(),
        AllEmployees = empList,
        RoleList = roles
    };
    return View(viewModel);
```

The Post Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeAttribute(Roles="Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //ModelState is invalid
            return View(new User());
        }
        try
        {
           //do stuff
        }
    }
```

The Required Helper Method (from [Define markup for [Required] fields in View in ASP.NET MVC 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974825/define-markup-for-required-fields-in-view-in-asp-net-mvc-2-0)):

```
    public static string RequiredMarkFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if(ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).IsRequired)
            return "*";
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post method should be as follows to get Server side validation...

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeAttribute(Roles="Administrator")]
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{
    if(!TryUpdateModel(user))
    {
       // Model is INVALID
       return View(user);
    }
    else
    {
        // ModelState is VALID
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

The `else` might be redundant depending on what you're doing but that should get you going.
In the view above your `<% using Html.BeginForm() %>` you need

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

You also need to reference the scripts, MicrosoftAjax and MicrosoftMvcValidation I think

Comment: How does TryUpdateModel work in reference to the ModelState?  And yes, all the scripts are referenced and client validation added, just didn't show it in the code.

Comment: Ok, I didnt see the code so I didnt want to assume.  TryUpdateModel is just a method I've consistenly used since someone suggested it to me on here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You have two closing form tags

If you use

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
<% } %>
```

you dont need to use this

```
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Regarding your validation problem you are using an editor only for your User property, which is the only one that get binded by the model binder

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, new { AllEmployees = Model.AllEmployees, RoleList = Model.RoleList })%>
```

Try to replace the previous code with an EditorForModel as your Editor Template is for a model class.

So your form should change in

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <table>
        <%:Html.EditorForModel()%>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add New User" />
    </p>
<% } %>
```

and you're done!

Comment: The purpose of using the editor only for the user is because the view uses a viewmodel in order to allow me to pass the two dropdown lists.  Are you suggesting that I just strongly type the view to the User, and pass the lists in the viewdata?

Comment: Your view is strong typed to the ViewModel. Your EditorTemplate create html markup for both the dropdown. If you just use `Html.EditorFor(model => model.User...` you're telling to the view to just bind one property to the view even if you're passing all the view model.

Comment: I tried that - same effect.  By the way thanks for pointing out the EndForm redundancy, didn't notice that.  Any other ideas?  I'm about to the point of just commenting out the [Required] annotation and moving on :P

Comment: what's the `RequiredMarkFor`? Also can you post the signature of your POST method?

Comment: Strangely, now it seems to validate on the server, but not on the client.

Comment: 'RequiredMark' just adds a "*" if the property is required.  It's a small helper method.  I'll update the question with the code, as well as the post method sig...